# Error importing 'getargspec' statsmodels

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I'm trying to do a logistic regression using statsmodels & an unable to import.  I'm using `statsmodels v0.8.0` with Python 3.x in a Jupyter notebook.  How am I able to import correctly?

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-6030a6549dc0> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels.api as sm

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/api.py in <module>()
      3 from . import tools
      4 from .tools.tools import add_constant, categorical
----> 5 from . import regression
      6 from .regression.linear_model import OLS, GLS, WLS, GLSAR
      7 from .regression.recursive_ls import RecursiveLS

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .linear_model import yule_walker
      2 
      3 from statsmodels import NoseWrapper as Tester
      4 test = Tester().test

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in <module>()
     51                                           cache_readonly,
     52                                           cache_writable)
---> 53 import statsmodels.base.model as base
     54 import statsmodels.base.wrapper as wrap
     55 from statsmodels.emplike.elregress import _ELRegOpts

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py in <module>()
      8 from statsmodels.stats.contrast import ContrastResults, WaldTestResults
      9 from statsmodels.tools.decorators import resettable_cache, cache_readonly
---> 10 import statsmodels.base.wrapper as wrap
     11 from statsmodels.tools.numdiff import approx_fprime
     12 from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import ValueWarning, \

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/wrapper.py in <module>()
      3 
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 from statsmodels.compat.python import get_function_name, iteritems, getargspec
      6 
      7 class ResultsWrapper(object):

ImportError: cannot import name 'getargspec'
```

Comment: That import line works correctly here (`statsmodels` 0.9.0), but I had a similar issue with `get_function_name`. Perhaps if you update your `statsmodels` to the newest version?